# A simple JaxWS Rest that accept JSON Object

Tags: java, json, rest

i'm trying to develop in Java a Rest WebService (i'm using RestEasy) that accept a generic JSonObject (i'm using JSON Simple 1.1.1).

What I've done so far:

```
@Path("/message")
public class TestRestService { 
    @POST
    @Path("/{param}")
    @Consumes("application/json") 
    public Response printMessage(JSONObject inputJsonObj) {

        String result = "Restful example : " + inputJsonObj;
     System.out.println(result);
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build(); 
    } 
}
```

And this is my client:

> ```
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>     try {
>
>       URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/myProject/rest/message/");
>       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>       conn.setDoOutput(true);
>       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
>       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
>
>       String input = "{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}";
>
>       OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
>       os.write(input.getBytes());
>       os.flush();
>
>       if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
>           throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
>               + conn.getResponseCode());
>       }
>
>       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
>               (conn.getInputStream())));
>
>       String output;
>       System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
>       while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
>           System.out.println(output);
>       } 
>       conn.disconnect();
>        } catch (MalformedURLException e) { } 
>       catch (IOException e) { } 
> }
> ```

Unfortunately i'm getting a 405 error, which means the path i suppose doesn't exist...

Can anybody help me?

thanks!

Comment: Response code 405 is _Method Not Allowed_. Are you missing the _{param}_ on your client URL?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the /{param}-part of your Path. Right now you have nothing following the part from /message but your webserver can not find a method which accepts just the pass to /message. Since you are not trying to use the /{param} in your method i would suggest you just remove the @Path-Annotation from your method. This is possible because the Framework will just try and use the @Path annotation on the next level (here this is your class-level and this would be your /message path) with the HTTP-method annotated to your method. If the /{param}  should be an optional parameter i would suggest using the @QueryParameter annotation in your method-head. For further information on this annotation you should read the docs for the javax.ws.rs framework.
Kind regards